# Pipe break error when reading piped program output

Tags: bash, ubuntu, text-processing, pipe

I'm doing something along these lines:

```bsh
declare -Ft handle_format_output &>/dev/null && exit 1   # test if this function name is already present in this scope
handle_format_output() {
    case $1 in
    domain) ./scripts/idn_to_punycode.pl >>"${2}_${1}.txt" ;;
    ipv4)
        # read doesn't bother w/ pipe input as its undefined: guessing it's leading to pipe breaks
        # therefore open stdin as a separate file and read from it to close the previous pipe
        while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
            case $line in
            */*) printf "%s\n" "$line" >>"${2}_${1}_cidr.txt" ;; # cidr block
            *-*) ipcalc "$line" >>"${2}_${1}_cidr.txt" ;;        # deaggregate ip range
            *) printf "%s\n" "$line" >>"${2}_${1}.txt" ;;        # ip address
            esac
        done 3< /dev/stdin
        ;;
    ipv6) cat -s >>"${2}_${1}.txt" ;;
    esac
}

...  |
  mawk '!seen[$0]++' | # filter duplicates and blank lines
  handle_format_output "$format" "$color"
```

Where the input is linear text that's either a web domain, IPv4 address, IPv4 CIDR block, or IPv6 address. The format is either "domain," "ipv4," or "ipv6." The color is either "white" or "black."

This error keeps being thrown no matter what I'm trying:

```
mawk: write failure (Broken pipe)
mawk: close failed on file /dev/stdout (Broken pipe)
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values of `$format` and `$color`? (please double check these and mention them in the question).

Comment: @Kusalananda I've added those details in the question

Comment: Could you please confirm that `$format` is actually exactly the string `ipv4` and nothing else (no trailing spaces or newline etc.)? You seem to think there's something wrong with your `read` call, so the first step is to make sure that the code actually gets there. If `$format` is a string that is not one of the three that you test for, the code will fall through that `case` statement and you'll get the behavior that you describe. You may therefore want to add a `*)` case that just prints `error!` or something, for debugging.

Comment: @Kusalananda If anything were different or more relevant it would've been documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Some of the format data fields were "ivp4" instead of "ipv4." I'm now wondering why there have been successful builds this long then, but after fixing them regular piping now works.

Comment: There is literally no difference between the code in your answer and the code in you question.  In both instances, your function reads the data from its standard input. The input is not "completely processed first" in your answer's code. It's redirected from a named pipe, which is effectively the same as piping it into the function. You obviously changed something else in the code or in the input data that made it work.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've changed nothing other than this line, and no error is thrown. From what I understand, this version waits until all the text is processed from the other commands, and passes the final output into the function. Before, there was still some processing going on, which is why the pipe broke when processing the output.

Comment: I don't really buy that as a reason unless there were some timeout while reading the data. Your code shows nothing that should be sensitive to timing out or reading lines with slight delays.

Comment: @Kusalananda Here's literally all I've changed if you want the full context: https://github.com/T145/the-blacklist/commit/22d2058f4f96fbb85a4cfa80960b3550f2e8058c After that change everything built perfectly, so if there's any way to do things better I'd love to learn it.

Comment: Try comparing `{ while true; do echo hello; sleep 1; done; } | while read; do echo "$REPLY"; done` and `while read; do echo "$REPLY"; done < <( while true; do echo hello; sleep 1; done )` and note how the second of these does not finish processing before sending the data to the `read` (the output is the same in both example, the string `hello` is repeatedly printed with a delay).  It is not clear that you are providing the new code with the same input as the old code.

Comment: @Kusalananda The input is exactly the same here. When I tried doing the normal pipe into my function originally it threw that error. My next attempt is what you see here, in trying to access STDIN directly. That yielded the same error. Here's the present script that's working: https://github.com/T145/the-blacklist/blob/master/scripts/create_builds.bash And yes, the input is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127176/discussion-between-t145-and-kusalananda).